# Ошибка с вычислением серверов на discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот сам код код который у меня не работает:

```py
#GG
@bot.command()
async def stat(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Статистика LiteBot',
    description=f'**Основная**\n**Серверов:** {guilds_count = len(bot.guilds)}\n**Платформа**\n**Задержка:** {round(bot.latency * 1000)}mc\n**Запущен**: <t:1635770881:D>',
    color= 0xff9900))
```

Вот ошибка:
[image]

**Замечания**
Если убрать вот это:

```py
guilds_count = len(bot.guilds)
```

То всё будет прекрасно работать

> Я перепробывал все возможные способы исправления но ничего не помогло, надеюсь тут мне помогут!

Comment: а что вам нужно?

Comment: Нужна команда которая показывает на скольки серверах находиться мой бот

Comment: Сделайте `len(bot.guilds)` вемсто `guilds_count = len(bot.guilds)`

Comment: Вов, сработало, спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отметьте решение:

```
@bot.command()
async def stat(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Статистика LiteBot',
    description=f'**Основная**\n**Серверов:** {len(bot.guilds)}\n**Платформа**\n**Задержка:** {round(bot.latency * 1000)}mc\n**Запущен**: <t:1635770881:D>',
    color= 0xff9900))
```